# No define call function in Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, requirejs

I have errors loading `jquery-menu-aim` and `bootstrap` with Require.js in backbone project.

Here are what I had defined in main.js of :

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
      //declare path jquery, backbone, underscore,and other library here....
      "jquery-menu-aim" : "libs/jquery/jquery.menu-aim",
      "bootstrap" : "libs/jquery/bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim: {
      "jquery-menu-aim" : {
        deps: ["jquery"] ,
        exports: "Jquerymenuaim"
       },
       "bootstrap" : {
        deps: ["jquery"] ,
        exports: "Bootstrap"
      }
   }
});
```

Errors  : Uncaught Error: No define call for jquery-menu-aim
          http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine require.js:8
          Uncaught Error: No define call for bootstrap
          http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine

When I defined it in my view. I think maybe I was wrong in defining library in Shim config, but I can not found it in google.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shim for Bootstrap is definitely wrong because Bootstrap does not define a symbol named `Bootstrap`. Here's what I use:

```
bootstrap: {
  deps: ["jquery"],
  exports: "jQuery.fn.popover"
},
```

The `jQuery.fn.popover` method is something that Bootstrap defines. If it is absent after RequireJS has loaded Bootstrap, that's a sure sign that Bootstrap has not loaded.

Your shim for jquery.menu-aim is similarly wrong. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/blob/master/jquery.menu-aim.js), I see it is a jQuery plugin. You should change your shim to check for a function it adds to jQuery. `jQuery.fn.menuAim` looks like a good candidate.

Comment: Works great, thanks Louis. But how could you know bootstrap exports is jQuery.fn.popover?

Comment: I've read Bootstrap's code. Another way to go about it would be to just read the doc and pick a method that the plugin you are using (Bootstrap acts as a plugin) makes available. So if the doc says that the plugin makes a new method named ``jQuery.foo`` available, you want to check for ``jQuery.fn.foo``. The ``.fn`` is necessary because that's where methods available on jQuery objects are stored.